# Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an issue in performing Hibernate Mapping. The scenario is as follows:

1. There is a User class which has username, name, dateofbirth, image and other information pertaining to a user with username as the primary key.
2. Second class is Product class which has product id and other information related to a product with primary key as product key.
3. The third class is Order class which has OrderId, OrderDate, Username- should be foriegn key-referring to the User class username and finally a Set of type Product- because one order can have many products.

Now I want the primary key of the Order class as a composite key (OrderId, ProductID) and this productID should be reference from Product Class.

The relationships that I want to create are as follows:
1. One order can belong to only one User
2. One order can have many products

Can someone lead me on how to go about it? Any kind of help will be great.

Comment: you can't have primary key for Order as orderid, productid - order has a lot of products. It should be just order id. If we are talking tables, there should be an OrderProduct table which will can orderid and productid as a key and this relationshipt will be mapped by Products set or something similar

Comment: I want one to many mapping between Order and Product. That is not possible without having a third table namely OrderProduct?

Comment: The compound primary key doesn't make much sense from a data-modeling perspective.  You are going to replicate a lot of data in your Orders object by including both Order and Product IDs in that table.

Answer (score 0):

I think most likely you are thinking similar relationship. Difference in your requirement is you need One to Many mapping from Order/PurchaseOrder to Product/Item and you don't want Shipment.

My suggestion would be:

1. Create bi-directional one-to-many relationship b/w User and Order. Benefit for bidirectional is you can access User Object from Order Object, if not required, you can keep it unidirectional from User to Order.
2. Create one-to-many relationship b/w Order and Product.
3. Instead of composite key in order, keep the primary key as just OrderID. You can still fetch list of products from your order object and order object from user object.

The whole point in making this decision is from which object you derive remaining objects. **With ORMs you should know from which object you would derive rest** and so my suggestion is based on assumption that you will have User object available as attached entity, so you can get list of orders (defined as set) and from a particular order find out list/set of Products.

In case you have Order object available first, then create a bidirectional with User. So that you can find list/set of Products at one end, and Customer associated at other.

For ORM mappings refer [Hibernate Mapping Examples.](http://www.tkhts.com/orm-tools/hibernate/examples.jsp)

Hope this clarifies.